# nginx reverse proxy to docker that is maybe offline

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy

I try to generate a nginx docker that will redirect my request to other dockers.

But it is possible that the other dockers are offline.

On stratup from my nginx docker i got the following error:

```
"host not found in upstream "es_dev" in "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

Is it possible to run a nginx that way? And if one of the dockers is no up, to show a html-error-page?

Here is my config file:

```
http {

  server {
    listen      80;
    server_name XXXXXXXXXXXXX.de;
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
  }

  server {
    listen 443;
    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_verify_depth 2;

    location /dev/ {
      proxy_pass http://dev:200/;
      resolver 127.0.0.11;
    }
    location /staging/ {
      proxy_pass http://staging:200/;
      resolver 127.0.0.11;
    }
    location /live/ {
      proxy_pass http://live:200/;  
      resolver 127.0.0.11;
    }
  }
}
```

2017:10.19:

First i run:

```
docker run --name nginx -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 nginx
```

Then:

```
docker run --link=nginx --name dev -d image1
```

Result: Nginx is returning an 502 - bad gateway

Comment: Links are deprecated, create docker network and attach your containers to that network for DNS discovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add resolver `resolver 127.0.0.11;` to your locations nginx will start when another containers are unavailable.

Your config must looks like:

```
http {

  server {
    listen      80;
    server_name XXXXXXXXXXXXX.de;
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
  }

  server {
    listen 443;
    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_verify_depth 2;

    location /dev/ {
      proxy_pass http://dev:200/;
      resolver 127.0.0.11;
    }
    location /staging/ {
      proxy_pass http://staging:200/;
      resolver 127.0.0.11;
    }
    location /live/ {
      proxy_pass http://live:200/;  
      resolver 127.0.0.11;
    }
  }
}
```

`127.0.0.11` is embedded docker DNS server

Comment: So now my ngix is starting... but i can't resolved to my docker dev:200

First i start nginx.
Then i start my docker.

But i nginx can not forawrd my request... i got an 502 - bad gateway error

Comment: i have suggested you use containerized nginx. Is this true? and how do you link containers?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it myself but following might be helpful for you:

https://sandro-keil.de/blog/2017/07/24/let-nginx-start-if-upstream-host-is-unavailable-or-down/

Essentially you need to refer upstream docker using a variable and use `resolver` directive. Let me know if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Someone wrote a community image that does what you're looking to do.

https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy